# is there any way to restrict data export?

Tags: contacts, permissions, export

Is there any way to restrict data export while still allowing users to see all data? I still want to give this permission '*View ANY CONTACT in the CiviCRM database, export contact info and perform activities such as Send Email, Phone Call, etc*.' but don't want them to be able to export the contacts. civi 4.6.11, drupal 7

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is now possible. I didn't hear from Kboy so I wrote an extension myself:

https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.exportpermission

Comment: Great - I just tested https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.exportpermission with 4.6.24, works like a charm!

Thank You!

Comment: Great work Jamie.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible as far as i know.

Your best chance is to create an extension that will :

1. remove export actions from the menu after a search if the user doesn't have enough permission by using hook_civicrm_searchTasks : https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_searchTasks
2. remove the export buttons from reports also. I guess you could do it by creating a alternative version of CRM/Report/Form/Actions.tpl that will check for the permissions before displaying the buttons. Yet, it still a display only hack and you might want to change CRM/Report/Form.php to ignore outputMode = csv...

Comment: I would be interested in such an extension - did you every write it? Can you share?

Comment: @Jamie, not yet just looked at this again today, will update if i make any progress