# Stop exporting to PDF/CSV etc

Tags: wordpress, permissions

Is it possible to restrict the ability for people to export to CSV/PDF/XML etc?

We want people to work out of Civi and this is one way I can see us achieving that goal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there any way to restrict data export?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/is-there-any-way-to-restrict-data-export)

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14868/is-there-any-way-to-restrict-data-export